# Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference on line 47

Tags: php

Hi guy's I'm having trouble with the above error with the following code, I have tried fixing it myself with the help from existing threads found on this site, please help.

```
<?php
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'];
$unique_id=uniqid();
$product_price=$_POST['product_price'];
$product_colour=$_POST['product_colour'];
$product_description=$_POST['product_description'];
$product_care=$_POST['product_care'];
$size=$_POST['size'];

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if (!$product_name || !$unique_id || !$product_price || !$product_colour || !$product_description || !$product_care || !$size) {
echo "You have not entered all the required details.<br />"
."Please go back and try again.";
exit;
}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$product_name = addslashes($product_name);
$unique_id = addslashes($unique_id);
$product_price = doubleval($product_price);
$product_colour = addslashes($product_colour);
$product_description = addslashes($product_description);
$product_care = addslashes($product_care);
$size = addslashes($size);
}

include "mysql.connect.php";

//Using Prepared Statements, they also protect against SQL injection-style attacks Addison Wesley (2008) PHP and Web Development 4th edn, p. 280
$query = "insert into products values(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if( ! $stmt = $db->prepare( $query ) ) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $db->error;
  return false; // throw exception, die(), exit, whatever...
} else {
  // the rest of your code
}
$stmt->bind_param("sssd", NULL, $product_name, $unique_id, $product_price, $product_colour, $product_description, $Sproduct_care, $size);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->affected_rows.'Item inserted into database.';
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Here's the mySQL table:

[image]

Comment: I counted 8 values, and 4 binds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssd", NULL, $product_name,...);
```

You can not pass `NULL` just like that. All arguments must be variable names that can be referenced.

Other thing is mentioned by @Fred-ii- in the comments: number of types does not match number of passed arguments. As for `NULL` value in first column, you are already using it in your query, so no need to pass it as parameter. Other thing that may not work as you expect is slashes in database. You are using prepared statement, so this fragment above:

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$product_name = addslashes($product_name);
...
}
```

will mess up your data.

Comment: Actually both `NULL` can be taken out, since `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and thanks for the mention ;-)

Comment: I've removed NULL and the section regarding magic quotes but now have the following error:

`Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you have removed NULL from your query, you are inserting 7 values into 8 column table, just as error informs you that column count doesn't match. If you want to skip any column from insert query, you have to specify these you wish to use. How to do it is explained in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Thanks for the help guy's, I now have this working perfectly!